Analytic continuation inherit invariance?

If a function $w_N$ on $(\mathbb{R}^{D})^{N-1}$ ($D$ and $N$ are integers) is invariant under  some transformations, is its analytic continuation to a set in $(\mathbb{C}^{D})^{N-1}$ also invariant under the transformations?
In my textbook, the transformation group is Lorentz group $L$ for $\mathbb{R}^{1,N-1}$ and the analytic continued set is denoted as $\mathscr{T}_{N-1}$.
I understand analytic continuation is unique but why analytic continued function is also invariant in the continued domain.
Any advice helps me. Thanks for reading.

Edit
BrunoB's comment made me understand for real Lorentz transformation case.
For complex Lorentz transformation case, there is unique analytic continuation of real Lorentz group to complex Lorentz group $L(\mathbb{C})$ in a neighborhood $U$ of $L$'s identity. This means $L\to \mathbb{C}, \Lambda \mapsto w_N(\Lambda \zeta_1,...)$  can be analytic continued around the identity to $U\to \mathbb{C}$. I don't understand how this leads to prove the invariance under complex Lorentz transformation.
Is there any idea to complete the proof?

I'm not well-versed in complex analysis of several variables, so I won't write it as an answer, but I assume the explanation is just like in the classical theory for one variable: you have the equality $w_N = w_N \circ \Lambda$ for $\Lambda \in L$ on $(\mathbb{R}^D)^{N-1}$ which has accumulation points in $\mathscr{T}_{N-1}$ on which both the LHS and RHS admit analytic extensions, hence by the uniqueness of analytic continuation you have $w_N = w_N \circ \Lambda$ on the bigger set.

You have to be more specific regarding "some transformations." Are these real linear transformations which you extend to complex linear transformations on the complexified space? How much complex analysis in several variables do you know?

@BrunoB I couldn't come up with the idea. It really helps! Thanks!

@MoisheKohan Thanks for giving advice. I specifically would like to know "real Lorentz transformations" case. I didn't understand why there is real Lorentz invariance in complexified space. I know complex analysis with one variable case to some extent but am not familiar with several variables case.
